# branch reset operator in perl 5.8.8

Tags: perl, version

I wanted to know how can i write a  regular expression compatible with Perl v5.8.8 and Perl v5.10.0 using branch rest operator?

i have written a perl code with regexp in it and the code is working fine with Perl v5.10.0 but when i execute the same code with perl v5.8.8 on another machine it gives following error;

```
Sequence (?|...) not recognized in regex; marked by <-- HERE in ...
```

here is the code;

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $i = "[1284336000] NEW SERVICE STATE: snpv3;service1;HIGH;SAFE;1;warnings";

if($i =~ /^\[\d+\]\sNEW\sSERVICE\sSTATE:\s(?|(snpv1);(service1)|(snpv1);(service2)|(snpv2);(service2)|(snpv3);(service1)|(snpv3);(service3)|(snpv4);(service4)|(snpv5);(service4)|(snpv6);(service6)|(snpv7);(service7));(HIGH);(\w+);(\d).+$/){
    print "matched\n";
}
else{
    print "not matched\n";
}
```

Could anyone suggest how to make a regexp which is compatible to either version.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

The branch reset operator isn't available until Perl 5.10 (as per `man perlre`), so if 5.8 is a requirement you'll have to write the regex without it.

Comment: oh! No, please don't tell me that.
i have different machines and some have v 5.8.8 and some have 5.10.0. 
If i have to change the code then everything needs to be modified.

may be the good option is to upgrade all systems to v5.10.0 but does this version has backward compatibility or not? i mean other perl code written with v5.8.8 would run with v5.10.0 or not? are there any compatibility backdrops?

Comment: If upgrading everything to 5.10 is an option, I'd recommend doing that. Perl's backwards compatibility is very good, so unless you're doing something really weird, it should work just fine. Just remember that a lot of modules (like DBI and the DBD::* drivers) depend on native code, so you'll have to reinstall those as well after upgrading your perl.

Comment: The perl5-porters go to great length to ensure that perl is backwards-compatible. You are ultimately responsible for _ensuring_ it does work on your code, though.

Comment: I have personally made 5.10 the baseline earliest version I will port my regex-based Perl programs to. Otherwise you lose access to too much. The numerous regex feature enhancements that first appeared in 5.10 are significant and many, and you really cannot reasonably and conveniently emulate them using other approaches as would be required to backport code to 5.8 or earlier. Named and relative capture groups, posessive groups, DEFINE blocks, group recursion, better Unicode props, improved `\X`, plus much more. And 5.12 makes the regex engine fully re-entrant, which you sometimes need or want.

Answer (score 3):

The `(?|...)` branch reset operator was added in Perl 5.10. If you want to make your regex backwards-compatible with earlier versions of Perl you'll need to modify it to remove the construct.

Here's your current pattern, written using the `/x` modifier for legibility:

```
my $pattern = qr/
    ^
    \[\d+\]
    \s
    NEW\sSERVICE\sSTATE:
    \s
    (?|
          (snpv1);(service1)
        | (snpv1);(service2)
        | (snpv2);(service2)
        | (snpv3);(service1)
        | (snpv3);(service3)
        | (snpv4);(service4)
        | (snpv5);(service4)
        | (snpv6);(service6)
        | (snpv7);(service7)
    )
    ;
    (HIGH);
    (\w+);
    (\d)
    .+
    $
/x;
```

Are the specific combinations of `snpv` and `service` important to a match/non-match? If not, it's easy to get rid of the `(?|...)` construct.

```
my $pattern = qr/
    ^
    \[\d+\]
    \s
    NEW\sSERVICE\sSTATE:
    \s
    (snpv\d);
    (service\d);
    (HIGH);
    (\w+);
    (\d)
    .+
    $
/x;
```

If the combinations are important you could still use this pattern, but you'd need to do a follow-up check.

```
my %valid = (
    snpv1 => { service1 => 1, service2 => 1 },
    snpv2 => { service2 => 1 },
    snpv3 => { service1 => 1, service3 => 1 },
    snpv4 => { service4 => 1 },
    snpv5 => { service4 => 1 },
    snpv6 => { service6 => 1 },
    snpv7 => { service7 => 1 },
);

if ($i =~ $pattern && $valid{$1}{$2}) {
    # match
}
else {
    # no match
}
```